# MySQL - Get the record with the longest string match

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string-matching

I am trying to write a query to get the longest string match, i get the word "antroid" from an ocr algorithm and the string i want to match with  is "android" so i want a query to match the two strings

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Google:  "MySQL levenshtein distance"

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that, after  Gordon Linoff hint, that LEVENSHTEIN is one good words distance function